# How to get <ui:repeat> out of the source code

Tags: html, jsf, uirepeat

I'm using ui:repeat like this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myClass.attribute}" var="foo">
     <h:outputText value="#{foo}"></h:outputText>
</ui:repeat>
```

I'm now asking myself why it writes ui:repeat into the source code of the html site. Is this intended?

```
<ui:repeat>Foo</ui:repeat>
```

I went trough the [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org) with the code and it tells this:

```
 Element ui:repeat not allowed as child of element body in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)
 Element name ui:repeat cannot be represented as XML 1.0.
```

Everything works fine with it but I don't think that this is right.

Comment: Have you added `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"` to your code?

Comment: Okay the url was wrong. I had this one: xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"

Comment: Does it work with the sun.com url?